# What is the equivalent updated name for 'TestButton' in the newest version of HoloToolKit? 2017.4.3.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm currently working on a new project using HoloToolKit 2017.4.3.0, and I'm trying to re-use some code that was written between May-August 2017, the version used was likely v1.5.7.0, HoloToolkit-Unity for Unity 5.6.1f1+

In the MixedRealityToolkit-Unity for Unity 2017.1.2f1 update, the Test and Example folders were merged, and in my old code I now have a deprecated object called TestButton.

Can someone direct me on what happened to TestButton and what I need to do to get my old code working in the newer version of the toolkit that I'm using?

private TestButton button = null;

I get a compilation error telling me "The type or namespace name 'TestButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I'm looking for the equivalent object type for 'TestButton' in 2017.4.3.0 but there's very poor documentation for the changes made. I posted this to the GitHub repository for the Mixed Reality Toolkit and no one responded. Just wondering if anyone here has any personal experience with updating old HoloToolKit apps from before they merged the Example and Test folders into newer versions. If anyone could just even point me to some documentation that lists and describes all the types in the SDK version I'm using that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you were using TestButton defined in [TestButton.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/v1.5.7.0/Assets/HoloToolkit-Tests/Input/Scripts/TestButton.cs), you can try use the [button_test_pfb.prefab](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/2017.4.3.0/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/Input/Prefabs) prefab provided in the version 2017.4.3.0.

Comment: @MichaelZhou After further research, the `TestButton.cs` is moved to [HoloToolkit-Examples](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/2017.4.3.0/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/Input/Scripts/TestButton.cs). Is it helpful after import this?